# How do I make custom location queries using Google Maps APIs?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a list of PlaceIds from Google Maps that I got from querying an external list of location names.

I now have a "search" feature where you enter your zip code, and it finds the closest 10 locations and shows them on a map. As far as I can tell, Google only lets you search by a search term.

How do I limit my search results only to the list of PlaceIds that I have present, and order it by distance?

NOTE: I don't have a "keyword" to search for that will include all my PlaceIds. These were retrieved from an external source, and there is no "common search keyword" that will return a super-set of my PlaceIds.

Comment: did you store the coordinates of the places too? How many places did you store?

Comment: Yes, I stored the lat/lng and have stored around 500 places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restricting the results of a PlacesSearch in that way currently is not possible.

Possible approach:

You'll also need a Database of ZIP-Codes(including the locations).

When your DB supports spatial queries you may use [`ST_DISTANCE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-distance) to order the results and use the 10 nearest results.

When your DB doesn't support spatial queries you may use the [haversine formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula) to calculate the distance

Of course the result may only be approximate, because a ZIP-code usually is related to an area, not to a location